# Alternative to using InStr

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

how can I use a different function "InStr"
this is the code that I am using and works fine but moving away from InStr is my goal

```
i = InStr(1, Hostname, Environment.Newline)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`String.Indexof()`  with several overloads:

```vb
Dim jstr = "How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck..."

' Find a character from a starting point
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("w"c)             ' == 2 (first w)
'  or within a range:
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("o"c, 12)         ' == 15 first o past 12 (cOuld)  

'Find a string
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("wood")           ' == 9
' ...from a starting point
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("wood", 10)       ' == 22 (WOODchuck)
' ...or in part of the string
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("chuck", 9, 15)   ' -1 (none in that range)

' using a specified comparison method:
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("WOOD", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)  ' 9
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("WOOD", nFirst, StringComparison) 
ndx = jstr.IndexOf("WOOD", nFirst, nLast, StringComparison)
```

There is also a [`String,LastIndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the last occurance of something in a string also with a variety of overloads.

Available in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) or Object Browser (VIEW menu | Object Browser) in the VS near you.

```vb
i = Hostname.Indexof(Environment.Newline, 1)
```

Comment: Do we add +1 at the end since Instr count starts from 1 but IndexOf() is 0 based?

Answer (score 8):

If you need equivalent C# code you can use `Strings` class from `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly, thus code can be like following:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
. . . 
i = Strings.InStr(1, Hostname, Environment.NewLine);
```

[image]

Another approach is using appropriate `String.Indexof` function.

Links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx

Comment: Good catch on the C# tag, must want it for both??? Anyways, you should avoid posting links that are version specific. IE, instead of your first link, try this [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx)